# HttpPost with Many to Many Relationship and Automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, many-to-many, viewmodel, dto

I´m working on a database with movies and genres (Many to Many). I have created an API and I´m struggling with the DTO's and the Many to Many relationship.

```
public class MovieDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OriginalTitel { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleseDate { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int? Rating { get; set; }
    public int? PersonalRating { get; set; }
    public int AgeRestrictionId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GenreDto> Genres { get; set; }
}

public class GenreDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

With the help of another Post, I have created this Mapping

```
public MappingProfile()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<Movie, MovieDto>();

    Mapper.CreateMap<Genre, GenreDto>()
        .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
        .ForMember(d => d.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Name));

    Mapper.CreateMap<MovieDto, Movie>()
          .AfterMap((s, d) =>
          {
              foreach (var Genre in d.Genres)
                  Genre.Id = s.Id;
          });

    Mapper.CreateMap<GenreDto, Movie>()
          .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id));
}
```

And this is my API Controller

```
public class MoviesController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public MoviesController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        // GET /api/movies
        public IHttpActionResult GetMovies()
        {
            return Ok(_context.Movies.ToList().Select(Mapper.Map<Movie, MovieDto>));
        }

        //GET /api/movies/1
        public IHttpActionResult GetMovie(int id)
        {
            var movie = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

            if (movie == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(Mapper.Map<Movie, MovieDto>(movie));
        }

        //POST /api/movies

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult CreateMovie (MovieDto movieDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest();

            var movie = Mapper.Map<Movie>(movieDto);
            _context.Movies.Add(movie);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Created(new Uri(Request.RequestUri + "/" + movie.Id), movieDto);
        }

        //PUT /api/movies/1
        [HttpPut]
        public void UpdateMovie(int id, MovieDto movieDto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

            var movieInDb = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

            if (movieInDb == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            Mapper.Map(movieDto, movieInDb);

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        //DELETE api/movies/1
        [HttpDelete]
        public void DeleteMovie(int id)
        {
            var movieInDb = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);

            if (movieInDb == null)
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

            _context.Movies.Remove(movieInDb);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

If I check the functionality with Postman, I can get the Data from the Database but if I try to Post something I get an error. The reason is the Genre but I don´t know if my mapping is wrong or if I need a kind of connection to my viewModel for the combination of the Movie and the Genre.
I tried a lot of things but I don´t really understand how to go with an API, Many to Many, Dtos, viewModel and Automapper. Can somebody give me an example and an explanation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you paste the data you were trying to post?

Comment: {
 "id": 18,
 "name": "Hangover",
 "originalTitel": "The Hangover",
 "releseDate": "2009-03-12T00:00:00",
 "duration": 100,
 "description": "Hangover",
 "rating": null,
 "personalRating": null,
 "ageRestrictionId": 4,
 "genres": [
     {
         "id": 3,
         "name": "Animation",
         "isChecked": false
     },
     {
         "id": 4,
         "name": "Comedy",
         "isChecked": false
     },
 ]
}
That´s what I get in the Postman Get and I copy this and try to post it. I think the format of the genre is wrong but I don´t know why or how to change it.

Comment: Removed additional comma, {
    "id": 18,
    "name": "Hangover",
    "originalTitel": "The Hangover",
    "releseDate": "2009-03-12T00:00:00",
    "duration": 100,
    "description": "Hangover",
    "rating": null,
    "personalRating": null,
    "ageRestrictionId": 4,
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Animation",
            "isChecked": false
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Comedy",
            "isChecked": false
        }
    ]
}

Comment: One more thing, make sure you have enabled the camel case transformation for MVC.

Comment: I have enabled the camel case and I removed the "," and it´s not working. That´s the error I get from postman.
"message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.\r\n\r\nMapping types:\r\nGenreDto -> Genre\r\nDreamy.Dtos.GenreDto -> Dreamy.Models.Genre\r\n\r\nDestination path:\r\nMovie.Genres.Genres.Genres0[0]\r\n\r\nSource value:\r\nDreamy.Dtos.GenreDto",
    "exceptionType": "AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException",

Comment: Where did you initialize the mapping? The error is clear that mapper cannot find map configuration for GenreDto to Genre.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tips I was really just missing this line:
Mapper.CreateMap<GenreDto, Genre>();
I thought a bit to much!